# Отправка запроса с файлом

Tags: python, upload, urllib

Вообще, проблема вроде расспространенная (должна быть теоретически таковой), а ее решения я найти не смог. При попытке считать файл .read() (.docx при эксперименте), а затем передать его через urllib2 выдается ошибка ‘ascii’ codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 228: ordinal not in range(128)
Если попытаться загрузить txt файл с латинскими симвоолами - все норм, если с кирилицей - ошибка. docx же в любом случае (не важно что там было) дает ошибку. Если просто сделать открытие файла и тут же его запись - все нормально… Но мне то нужно его передать
Колдовство с кодировками не помогло… 
Или я что-то совсем не так делал?

Вот код. Класс для передачи файла взят [здесь](http://python.su/forum/topic/7182/).

```
    self.boundary = mimetools.choose_boundary()
    return
def get_content_type(self):
    return 'multipart/form-data; boundary=%s' % self.boundary
def add_field(self, name, value):
    """Add a simple field to the form data."""
    self.form_fields.append((name, value))
    return
def add_file(self, fieldname, filename, fileHandle, mimetype=None):
    """Add a file to be uploaded."""
    body = fileHandle.read()
    if mimetype is None:
        mimetype = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)[0] or 'application/octet-stream'
    self.files.append((fieldname, filename, mimetype, body))
    return
def __str__(self):
    """Return a string representing the form data, including attached files."""
    # Build a list of lists, each containing "lines" of the
    # request.  Each part is separated by a boundary string.
    # Once the list is built, return a string where each
    # line is separated by '\r\n'.
    parts = []
    part_boundary = '--' + self.boundary
    # Add the form fields
    parts.extend(
        [ part_boundary,
          'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"' % name,
          '',
          value,
        ]
        for name, value in self.form_fields
        )
    # Add the files to upload
    parts.extend(
        [ part_boundary,
          'Content-Disposition: file; name="%s"; filename="%s"' % \
             (field_name, filename),
          'Content-Type: %s' % content_type,
          '',
          body,
        ]
        for field_name, filename, content_type, body in self.files
        )
    # Flatten the list and add closing boundary marker,
    # then return CR+LF separated data
    flattened = list(itertools.chain(*parts))
    flattened.append('--' + self.boundary + '--')
    flattened.append('')
    return '\r\n'.join(flattened)
```

---

```
UnicodeDecodeError at /client/upload/
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 128: ordinal not in range(128)

Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  77.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/vagrant/softfacade/ctrl.lc-Web/CtrlLcWeb/apps/lib/views.py" in wrapper
  104.         return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/vagrant/softfacade/ctrl.lc-Web/CtrlLcWeb/apps/client/views.py" in upload
  94.     return HttpResponse(uploader.handleUpload(request, os.path.dirname(__file__)))      
File "/vagrant/softfacade/ctrl.lc-Web/CtrlLcWeb/apps/lib/upload.py" in handleUpload
  75.                 urllib2.urlopen(request)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py" in urlopen
  126.     return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py" in open
  391.         response = self._open(req, data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py" in _open
  409.                                   '_open', req)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py" in _call_chain
  369.             result = func(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py" in http_open
  1185.         return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py" in do_open
  1154.             h.request(req.get_method(), req.get_selector(), req.data, headers)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py" in request
  955.         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py" in _send_request
  989.         self.endheaders(body)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py" in endheaders
  951.         self._send_output(message_body)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py" in _send_output
  809.             msg += message_body
```

Comment: Еще бы полный текст ошибочки не помешал

Comment: Спасибо за текст ошибки. Я так и не смог понять, в какой строке твоего кода вываливается ошибка, но в целом проблема описана - [How do I post non-ASCII characters using httplib when content-type is “application/xml”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993175/how-do-i-post-non-ascii-characters-using-httplib-when-content-type-is-applicati) где-то внутри юникодная строка пытается соединится с обычной стрингой. Как вариант попробуй `return u'\r\n'.join(flattened)` в методе `__str__`

Comment: Не помогло :( Буду искать где ещё может быть

Comment: дебажить нужно

Comment: Нашел кой-чего: `['--127.0.1.1.0.2454.1350641942.724.1', u'Content-Disposition: file; name="file"; filename="ss.txt"', 'Content-Type: text/plain', '', 'sdsd\xf0\xf0\xe2\xe0', '--127.0.1.1.0.2454.1350641942.724.1--', '']` это flattened переменная... собственно видно, где находится unicode.. Как бы его теперь преобразовать не в unicode..

Comment: Если ты о `'sdsd\xf0\xf0\xe2\xe0'`, то это не юникод 

`type('sdsd\xf0\xf0\xe2\xe0')
<type 'str'>`

Происходит следующее (эквивалент ошибки)

`unicode('sdsd\xf0\xf0\xe2\xe0')`

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#130>", line 1, in <module>
    'sdsd\xf0\xf0\xe2\xe0'.decode()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)`

Нужно подготовить строку

`unicode('sdsd\xf0\xf0\xe2\xe0', 'cp1251')
u'sdsd\u0440\u0440\u0432\u0430'`

Осталось найти где, и какая кодировка

Comment: В общем, текстовый файл удалось передать так: 
parts.extend(
            [ part_boundary,
              u'Content-Disposition: file; name="%s"; filename="%s"' % \
                 (field_name, filename),
              u'Content-Type: %s' % content_type,
              u'',
     ------->body.decode('cp1251'),
            ]
            for field_name, filename, content_type, body in self.files
            )
И u'\r\n'.join(flattened).encode('utf-8')     
Теперь настала очередь doc файла и он ругается на вот такое:'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 880: character maps to <undefined

Comment: Если убрать body.decode('cp1251') и вернуть body, то снова на acsii ругается, то есть нужно определять как-то кодировку?.

Comment: судя по всему word по умолчаню дает unicode.. Как объяснить python, что это unicode и не надо его преобразовывать в unicode, чтобы получить unicode:)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> isinstance('aaa', unicode)
False
>>> isinstance(u'aaa', unicode)
True
>>>
```

Comment: Да, по сути файл ворда не считается юникодным... Но он полностью состоит из юникода.. Вычитал, что ворд вообще хранит данные в юникоде.. Отсюда вопрос, как сделать строку юникод без каких-либо преобразований.. Просто дать ей уникодную метку. Я где-то видел, что кажись можно отключить проверку ошибок на свой страх и риск) мне хотя бы для эксперимента)

Comment: нашел сам unicode (body,errors='ignore')

Comment: У меня очередная веха :) Перед return '\r\n'.join(flattened) - все норм. Когда выполняется эта команда - файл сбивается в крякозяблы вместо байтовой записи( такое чувство, что питон зачем то произвел encode.. Почему и как это отменить?

Content-Disposition: file; name="file"; filename="dd.docx"
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document

XKnDUContent_Types].xml (Tn0W?D8H`
     A*)Yl      1iJ/z,'nVK~)am j0HuT9bx<9X
Q
8AO1~qk
I~8WZ"V0}>uQwHoP!N_UZB_%D[S+?#[.z9>$N{9+P9Y vuGDoR
                 _rels/.rels (JA

Answer (score 0):

Вам ведь уже дали правильный ответ во втором комментарии (до строчек `u'\r\n'.join(flattened)`) + привели ссылку на решение вашей проблемы.

У вас действительно где-то в списке (переменная `flattened`) закралась юникодная строка.
Вот пример конкатенации строк:

```
>>> 'hello' + u'hello'
u'hellohello'
```

Это значит, что если вы объединяете две строки одна из которых `unicode`, `Python` автоматически пытается декодировать вторую в `unicode`, а после уже объединять их воедино.

А теперь задайтесь вопросом, что произойдет, если `Python` попытается преобразовать байткод прочитанного вами файла (в неизвестной кодировке) в `unicode`?
Ответ:

```
>>> unicode(open('test.docx', 'rb').read())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Ваша задача, пройтись по каждому элементу списка (переменная `flattened`) и проверить является ли данный элеменет `unicode` строкой, и если это так, преобразовать его в строку `ascii`, а еще правильней в `utf-8` (для поддержки кириллицы), а после уже выполнять конкатенацию:

```
'\r\n'.join(flattened)
```